# What is direct file upload feature in PHP 5.5 on GAE?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, php-5.5

I gotten an mail from Google about PHP 5.5 runtime and list of new features in it. One of them is listed as support for direct file upload. Can any one explain what does that mean.

Does this mean that I can upload files to the temp directory, extract the data and then destroy the file?

Comment: Can you add the relevant extract of that email, so we can read it for ourselves?

Comment: yes that's what it means - as long as the total upload is < 32MB.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/y6WX6EMnYO4/DlOIAzbYwbwJ

that's the link in the email

Comment: The changes include:
Support for the PHP 5.5 runtime, alongside the current PHP 5.4 runtime.
The cURL extension is now available, meaning curl_*() functions can now be used from within your application (read more about how to enable cURL support in our documentation).
The tempnam() and sys_get_temp_dir() functions are available.
Support for direct file uploads.
Support for concurrent requests,which allows the PHP interpreter to run an efficient multi-threaded mode when serving HTTP requests.This must be enabled in your app.yaml file.
Support for the ImageMagick extension and MongoDB extension

Comment: @StuartLangley can you have a sample of how it works. This is a long sought which will help in manipulating small files and data. And thanks for the limit info, didn't know about it and will not be uploading that big of a file either.

Comment: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/

Comment: something odd is happening..
if I do a deployment and then hit submit without attaching a file I get an empty $_FILES when I do print_r. But if I attach a file or do another empty submit I keep getting Array ( ) Notice: Undefined index: userfile 

should I raise an issue?

Comment: @StuartLangley reported a bug https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11765

From what I find CloudStorageTools is missing in the new sdk 1.9.18.

Comment: @StuartLangley question: the way the path is implemented in 1.9.18 (Root Path - gs://app_default_bucket) is it different for premier account?  I am lost at this moment for what ever reason I can not get a default bucket to this app abilasha3a, works in development just not in live.

Comment: @StuartLangley thx for your help and please do say thanks to mars..@google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link has the instructions how to do direct file upload.

https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/

Thanks @StuartLangley

What I found is that old apps have to enable a settings called **cloud integration**.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/activate

> That explains it. Please go to App Engine admin console
>   (https://appengine.google.com), choose "Application Settings" on the
>   left, click on "Create" button under "Cloud Integration" section, and
>   you should have a default gcs bucket created.

Thx @mars..@google.com

Also this part of the code

```
// Direct uploads requires PHP 5.5 on App Engine.
if (strncmp("5.5", phpversion(), strlen("5.5")) < 0) {
    die("Direct uploads require the PHP 5.5 runtime.");
}
```

Does not actually tell you if your version is 5.5. I have been running 5.4 for days and it didn't dawn on me as I thought this would work blindly.

A more working model is this one

```
// Direct uploads requires PHP 5.5 on App Engine.
if (strncmp("5.5", phpversion(), strlen("5.5")) != 0) {
    die("Direct uploads require the PHP 5.5 runtime.");
}
```

Hope this helps any one who is working on direct file uploads for PHP in GAE. Now I can start working on my csv files yay.